# MySQL Procedure unable to perform as expected

Tags: mysql, procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `userCredentialsWeight`(IN data1 varchar(50), IN data2 varchar(250))
BEGIN

    /* all declaration */

    IF (SELECT field1 FROM user_credentials WHERE field1 = data1 LIMIT 1 )
    THEN
        SET DATA_WEIGHT = 75;
    ELSE
        SET DATA_WEIGHT = 100;
    END IF;

    /* More calculations here */  ---> this block contains all the calculation,
 actually i am new to procedure, i have done this using 
direct query from application but it requires 4 database requests 
which I want to minimize here

END
```

Now my issue is the condition after WHERE is not getting a value of data1.

Platform - Mysql (i am using MYSQL Workbench)

Comment: What does you want? to set `DATA_WEIGHT = 75` if a record with `user_credentials.field1 = data1` exists and 100 if not exists?

Comment: I have modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 
            THEN 100
            ELSE 75
            END
INTO data_weight 
FROM user_credentials
WHERE field1 = data1;
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: how can I do in this format -->IF (SELECT field1 FROM user_credentials WHERE field1 = data1 LIMIT 1 )

Comment: I mean inside if condition